# Running time of a function of n with while loop

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Provide a tight Θ bound on the running time of the function of n.

```
a = n
   while ( a > 1 or a > 2 or a > 3)
      for b = 1 to n
         print "Hello World"
      a = sqrt(a)
```

Would the running time be dependent on the condition set in the while loop? Currently my answer for this is nlog(n) but I am not sure if that is correct? Can someone clarify? I thinking the sqrt makes it log(n)

Comment: Seems more like of the order of `log(log(n))` to me.

Comment: @Did Can you explain why?

Comment: Because the running time for `n=2^2^k` is `1+` the running time for `n=2^2^(k-1)`.

Comment: that is what I do not see, can you provide a bit of an explanation? I am really curious to know why it is that

Comment: Hint: if `n=2^2^k`, what is `sqrt(n)`?

Comment: would it be 2^k ? I see how you got n=2^2^k and then you take log of both sides and get there

Comment: @Masterminder Try from the other side, e.g. what is the order of sequence $2, 2^2, (2^2)^2, ((2^2)^2)^2, \ldots$?

Comment: If `n=2^(2^k)` then `sqrt(n)` is not `2^k`. Please think again.

Comment: @Did my mistake it is 2^2^(k-1)

Comment: @dtldarek i see what you mean by that where it came from

Comment: @Did so is the final runtime of the function log(log(n)? Why is it not nlog(log(n)? There is a for loop inside which occurs n iterations so even if i is sqrt then it still executes

Comment: See answer, which includes the `for` loop I had overlooked when writing my first comments (sorry about that...).

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inner loop (the one based on `for b = 1 to n`) uses `n` steps. Then `n` is replaced by `sqrt(n)` hence the second inner loop uses `sqrt(n)` steps, and so on. This shows the run time is `n + sqrt(n) + sqrt(sqrt(n)) + ...`

If `n = 2^(2^k)` then `sqrt(n) = 2^(2^(k-1))`, `sqrt(sqrt(n)) = 2^(2^(k-2))`, and so on, hence there are `k` terms in the sum above. Thus, for some general `n`, there are about `log(log(n))` terms. Counting the first loop separately, one sees that the run time is more than `n` and less than `n + sqrt(n) * log(log(n))`. Finally, the run time is equivalent to `n`, in particular it is `Θ(n)`.